# Java Exception Translator Utility

Tags: java, google-app-engine, exception

I have a typical RESTful web service with two layers. A resource layer and a service layer. The DAO layer seems obsolete with modern object relational mapping libraries.

I am using Google Cloud Endpoints which not surprisingly returns HTTP errors in the form of Java Exceptions. I have a dedicated set of Exceptions the service layer can throw, such as an Object Not Found Exception, from the object relational mapping library, and other internal exceptions. Suffice to say, each internal exception has an HTTP Exception counterpart.

In order for a resource to safely call a service method, the call is surrounded in a series of try catches.

```
try {
    resourceObject = CorrespondingService.method(...);

} catch (InternalExceptionOne internalExceptionOne) {
    throw new CorrespondingWebExcpetionOne(internalExceptionOne.getMessage());

} catch (InternalExceptionTwo internalExceptionTwo) {
    throw new CorrespondingWebExcpetionTwo(internalExceptionTwo.getMessage());

} catch (InternalExceptionThree internalExceptionThree) {
    throw new CorrespondingWebExcpetionThree(internalExceptionThree.getMessage());
}
```

Since every call to a service method from the resource layer must be wrapped in the same series of try catch statements this creates a lot of repeated code.

I was looking to create a Utility that could act as a WebExcpetionTranslator, but I would have to pass it a method to be run under a try catch. Not sure how to pass a method and parameters, and then how to subsequently call said passed method.

This seems a bit sloppy though? Its there any thing out there that might do this with annotations?

**How can I pass a method and arbitrary parameters to a utility method, and subsequently call the passed method with the parameters?**

***What about annotations? Can you make a custom annotation to handle different exceptions?***

P.S. My technology stack is GAE, Objectify, and Google Cloud Endpoints.